# How to draw a circle css

Tags: css

I have following table:

```
   <table>
     <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td>Other Color</td>
        <td class="Green">Green<td/>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

and want to draw green circle in last column. 
CSS:

```
.Green{
    font-size:0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: green!important;
    border:solid black 3px;}
td {
   border:solid black 3px;}
```

I need to draw borders for the cell, but when doing so it is drawing border around the circle, not the cell. 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/Ulee/up3a5fp4/
any tip?

Comment: Well, the cell is the circle and so what else were you expecting :) Put another element inside the `td` and make it as the circle if you don't want the cell to be a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.green:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.green {
  font-size: 0;
}

td {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>Other Color</td>
    <td class="green">Green</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.Green{
   border:solid green 3px;
   font-size:0px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   display:inline-block;
   background: green!important;  
}
td {
  border:solid black 3px;
}
```

And your html contain a little mistake, your html is:
   **`<td/>`**, but the correct format is: **`</td>`**